# Effect of jade contact on tainted individuals

Tags: l5r, l5r-4e

My PCs are in a court where they suspect someone to be Tainted, but they are not sure who. There are actually several Tainted individuals, with a Taint score between 2.0 and 4.0. They have some jade fingers, and they figured they could use them in some way.

They came up with two plans:

- Touching everyone with the fingers, in a way or another, and see what happens
- Crushing the fingers into fine powder, mixing it with tea, and serving it to everyone

Without focusing too much on how they can achieve their goal, or how they can even complete their plans, what would happen in both those situations?

***What happens to a Tainted person who touches/ingests jade?***

Answer (score 6):

Depending on which edition you are using, there could be different effects.  Since all I have with me at the moment is my 4th edition book I'll provide you with this:

**Page 277: Levels of Taint Infection**

> Level 1 - Passive Infection: *...jade will now burn the character's skin...*

Therefore one of your methods will have a very serious and immediate reaction.  Not only this, but a character does not get past having the first full rank without getting some noticeable symptoms like becoming pale, sickly, and mentally unstable.  These problems only escalate until they are completely obvious especially through the mutations they begin to undergo with the Taint.  Therefore a character with 4 ranks of Taint will need some very specific powers (Such as *Beside the Darkness*) to conceal the side effects of being this far along so that anyone with at least an Air and Water 1 will notice.

In addition, don't forget the mental symptoms like hallucinations for all the senses, fits of anger (Willpower TN 15 for Taint 4) and the like because higher levels of Taint will skill cause (albeit unkept dice) penalties. I would also advise that characters with Lore: Shadowlands, Lore: Maho, and Spellcraft be able to spot things more easily.  Not all Tainted/Lost are purely physical beings so if Kansen are floating around, even a simple Commune spell can accidentally draw the wrong attention or reveal around whome these dark things are floating.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, thanks! Also, all those characters have the Unholy Beauty power, hence their current mission infiltrating the court. Thanks again!

Comment: Slight edit with that new info.  With more insight into the party/situation I'll tailor the answer.

Comment: Do keep in mind that either approach has the later challenge of provability - "grinding up something and putting it in the tea and then a couple people get hurt from it" could get them arrested for poisoning just as easily as getting the tainted individuals fingered, depending on who believes whom (and in Rokugan crime has a lot more to do with station and honor than "the truth of the matter"...)

Comment: Don't forget that testing someone for taint is considerably rude and would qualify as, at least, a minor breach of etiquette.

Comment: Agreed entirely, but I'm just here to say how it's done.